# Typing partial column names yields values in that column

Tags: r

Sorry if this seems like a rookie question, but it messed me up: Is it standard that you are allowed to enter the partial name of the column and it will not throw an error, but "guess" based on the name? For example:

```
d = data.frame(test = c(1,2,3,4),
           tmp = c(5,6,7,8),
           tmp1 = c(9,10,11,12))
```

If I type 'd$te' I get:

```
d$te
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

but if I type:

```
d$tm
NULL
```

I would have preferred to get an error when I type `d$tes`. Is this default behavior and can this be changed?

Comment: `data.frame` and `data.table` use non strict subsetting, but no `tibble`

Comment: Moving this into a comment since it's likely already been answered, but: you should use `d[["test"]]` since `$` does partial matching. Thus `d[["tes"]]` or `d[["tm"]]` both return `NULL`.

Comment: You can also use `d[, "test"]` to enforce exact referencing of base R data.frames.

Comment: Thanks - I couldn't find reference to this "feature" using my Google Fu. I will keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known 'feature'. Instead, switch your data.frame to a tibble:

```
library(tibble)
d <- as_tibble(d)
d$te

NULL
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'te'.
```